# Shard Postgresql Schemas into different databases clusters

Tags: postgresql, schema, partitioning, sharding

Currently postgresql offeres to shared at table level where the rows of a table are distributed across multiple nodes. I have an application which is multi-tenant.
The multi-tenancy is achieved by creating individual schema for each user. All schemas have the same set of tables.
With increase in number of users, the number of schemas in single node will increases which might lead to permformance issues.
I am looking for postgresql plugins or ways where the schemas can be sharded to different nodes in a cluster.

-- Edit --  A multi-master cluster where there is one-endpoint exposed for all the writer instances in the cluster. Each instance having own postgres server running

I have looked into different plugins to help with shard like CitusDB or Postgres XC but the sharding is acheived at table level.

Comment: When you say "cluster" are you referring to the "data directory" which is referred to as a [database cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html). Or do you mean a group of independent servers each running their own instance of Postgres?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: A multi-master cluster where there is one-endpoint exposed for all the writer instances in the cluster. Each instance having own postgres server running

Comment: Postgres does not have multi-master replication